# URLSessionTask runs always into an error

Tags: xcode, swift3, watchos-3

In my ExtensionDelegate I'm starting a URLSessionTask with following code:

```
func scheduleNextURLSessionTask() {
    let backgroundConfigObject = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "myIdentifier")

    let backgroundSession = URLSession(configuration: backgroundConfigObject, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    let retrieveTask = backgroundSession.dataTask(with: URL(string: "https://api.wedtec.net/cryptocoins/index.php?bitcoin&simple")!)
    retrieveTask.resume()
}
```

My ExtensionDelegate implements URLSessionDataDelegate, of course.
This runs always into an error. Means

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?)
```

Will be triggered will following error message:

> URLSessionTask didCompleteWithError  Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-997 "Lost connection to background transfer service" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.wedtec.net/cryptocoins/index.php?bitcoin&simple, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.wedtec.net/cryptocoins/index.php?bitcoin&simple, NSLocalizedDescription=Lost connection to background transfer service})

Any Idea what could be wrong here? scheduleNextURLSessionTask is called from a background process (WKApplicationRefreshBackgroundTask).

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple documentation, only download and upload tasks can be scheduled for executing as background tasks:

*"Only upload and download tasks are supported (no data tasks)."*

Check [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsession), under "Background transfer considerations"-