# NSURLSession doesn't return data

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

I try to download a zip-archive using `NSURLSessionDataTask`.
I am aware that there is a `NSURLSessionDownloadTask`, but the point is I want a `didReceiveData` callback (to show the progress).

The code is:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:@"..."
cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
timeoutInterval:60.0];

NSURLSessionConfiguration* config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSOperationQueue *myQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];
myQueue.underlyingQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config
delegate:self 
delegateQueue:myQueue];

NSURLSessionDataTask* task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
completionHandler:^( NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){ ... }

[task resume];
```

My class conforms to `NSURLSessionDataDelegate`.

When I call the method, after several seconds debugger goes to completionHandler with `nil` data and `nil` error. 
What am I doing wrong?

I also tried:

- calling without completionHandler, then debugger goes to `didReceiveResponse` callback with 200 response and that's all.
- using `[NSOperationQueue new]` for the queue
- using `[NSURLSession sharedSession]` - didn't get *any* response
- using `[NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier: @"..."]` - falls saying that I can't use a completionHandler, but without it - also no response.

Comment: You got two options: 1) Use delegate  and implement the necessary delegate methods 2) Use completion handler. The options are **not** mixable. `didReceiveData` belongs to *delegate*. `dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:` belongs to *completion handler*

Comment: Yeah but even if I'm using one of them it doesn't send me any data.

Comment: Basically *callback with 200* is good. Did you implement the other delegate methods which pass the data?

Comment: Yes I implemented this one:  `- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *) session
          dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *) dataTask
    didReceiveData:(NSData *)data`

Comment: At least implement also `didFailWithError` to get a possible error.

Comment: I did that, too

Comment: It says `lost connection to background trasnfer service`, so that's already something...

Comment: Maybe the `main` operation queue breaks the (background) functionality. Try `NSOperationQueue.currentQueue`

Comment: Tried. Still it sends me 200 and then nothing.

Comment: Maybe this is useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39390388/urlsessiontask-runs-always-into-an-error ?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. It seems I have found out what the problem is :)

Answer (score 1):

So I have found the answer and it's not quite obvious from documentation:
I had several callbacks, and among them [`didReceiveResponse`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessiondatadelegate/1410027-urlsession).

Turns out **I have to call completion handler** in order for the future callbacks to work, i.e:
`completionHandler(NSURLSessionResponseAllow);`

And one more thing: [`didCompleteWithError`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessiontaskdelegate/1411610-urlsession) is actually the delegate that tells about successful finish, too, although the name implies that this is the error handler.
What it means: when a download is successfully finished, this function is called with error = `nil`.

Hope this will be useful for somebody someday.